# I am I using the correct function for my element to turn red?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok so am trying to get just my headers (all 3 headers) to turn the color red when the "Red Headings"  button is clicked by using the changeStuff function but it doesn't seem to run properly. So Is this the correct function I should be using?

```
<title>Stanford Graduation</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .redElements {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>


  <h1>Graduation</h1>

  <p>Graduation is the culmination of four (or more years of hard work).</p>

  <h2>Graduation Traditions</h2>

  <p>Stanford Graduation has it's own amazing traditions.</p>

  <h3>The Wacky Talk</h3>

  <p>Stanford Seniors act and dress wacky as they enter the stadium.</p>

  <h3 id="speakerHeading">Speakers</h3>

  <p>Stanford graduation speakers always have Stanford ties.</p>

  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Red Headings" id="theRedButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Fade Out Speaker" id="theSpeakersButton" />
  </div>

  <script>
    "jquery-2.1.4.js"
  </script>
  <script>
    function changeStuff() {
      $("h").addClass("redElements");
    }
    $("theRedButton").bind("click", changeStuff);
  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: `$("h")` should be `$("h1")` and/or `$("h2")`

Comment: Also, you're not adding jQuery correctly: `<script>"jquery-2.1.4.js"</script>` is wrong. Try: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: also this , `$("#theRedButton").bind("click",changeStuff);` , use # when referring to id and . when referring to class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors.

Change it to

```
function changeStuff() {
    $("h1,h2,h3").addClass("redElements");
}
$("#theRedButton").bind("click", changeStuff);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2oj1s9mg/

Also

```
<script>
    "jquery-2.1.4.js"
</script>
```

Should be

`<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>`

Comment: does it matter where I put the <script> tag at like inside the div or outside because I've changed everything and it's still not working?

Comment: I added you edits to my code and it's still not working that's why i was asking does it matter where I put the script at ?

Comment: Can you output all of your code. Have you checked for errors in a console?

Answer (score 2):

To add the class to all header elements, use:

```
function changeStuff() {
    $("h1, h2, h3").addClass("redElements");
}
$("#theRedButton").on("click", changeStuff);
```

**Edit**: Here's the complete HTML content you need, which also shows how you should be bringing in jQuery and hooking into the document ready callback:

```
<head>
    <title>Stanford Graduation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .redElements {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Graduation</h1>

    <p>Graduation is the culmination of four (or more years of hard work).</p>

    <h2>Graduation Traditions</h2>

    <p>Stanford Graduation has it's own amazing traditions.</p>

    <h3>The Wacky Talk</h3>

    <p>Stanford Seniors act and dress wacky as they enter the stadium.</p>

    <h3 id="speakerHeading">Speakers</h3>

    <p>Stanford graduation speakers always have Stanford ties.</p>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Red Headings" id="theRedButton" />
        <input type="button" value="Fade Out Speaker" id="theSpeakersButton" />
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#theRedButton").on("click", changeStuff);
        });
        function changeStuff() {
            $("h1, h2, h3").addClass("redElements");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And here's a working pen showing it in action: http://codepen.io/Ghazgkull/pen/rVRRbK

Comment: do I need to put it inside the div?

Comment: like so >>> $(document).ready(function changeStuff() {
    $("h1, h2, h3").addClass("redElements");
})
$("#theRedButton").bind("click", changeStuff);

Comment: @Jarri I've updated my answer to include everything you need in one package. Please remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("h1,h2,h3").addClass("redElements");
```

There is no element name `h`

For id jquery use `#` .

Without `#` jquery treated provided selector as element

Add like this

```
$("#theRedButton").bind("click",changeStuff);
```

Comment: you can't have multiple IDs on a page - so you don't want to use `#`. You want to use classes

Answer (score 0):

`$("#theRedButton").bind("click",changeStuff);`

added a # for select by id

and the `$('h')` should be `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5');`//or whatever you want to get that class on the page

Also I can see the jquery I hope you tried to demo a pseudo code else you have to include jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl ya actually . added the second part